# how do dynamic reactiveFormsModule with patterns generate by api

Tags: angular, regex

I have an angular form group with an input mail but I want to add regex patterns for the extension for only what its in my database.

My services getAllDomain is done.

I don't know how to write the regex any word that does not end @ and a word from my list not case-similar

i think trigger action like that `[pattern]="patternEmail"`

```js
  getpatternEmail(){
domainList: string[] = [];
this.domainService.getAll().subscribe({
      next:(res) => {
        domainList=res;
    }});
    
    return ".@("+domainList.join('|')+")";
  }
```

`Property 'patternEmail' does not exist on type 'CreateComponent'`

and if i remove the get
`Type '() => string' is not assignable to type 'string | RegExp'.`

Answer (score 0):

something like this should work

```js
get patternEmail(): string{
    domainList: string[] = [];
this.domainService.getAll().subscribe({
      next:(res) => {
        domainList=res;
    },
      error: (e) => {
      },
      () => {
        // 'onCompleted' callback.
        // No errors
       return ".@("+domainList.join('|')+")";
      }
    );
  }
```